# UINavigationController's nav bar seems invisible, but title and buttons are still visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa

I've run into a weird situation. This is all done in code - no Interface Builder.

I'm creating a `UIViewController` and adding some content to it:

```
UIViewController* popoverViewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

UIView* popoverContentView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
popoverContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
// Add some stuff to popoverContentView

popoverViewController.view = popoverContentView;
```

I then create a `UINavigationController`, set its root view controller to the `UIViewController` from above, and add a title and a button to the `navigationItem`:

```
UINavigationController* popoverNav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popoverViewController] autorelease];
popoverViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(dismissPopover)] autorelease];
[popoverViewController.navigationItem setTitle:@"MY TITLE"];
```

Then I set up a `UIPopoverController` with the `UINavigationController` in it and present it:

```
self.popoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverNav] autorelease];
self.popoverController.delegate = self;

[self.popoverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 216) animated:NO];
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:self.cell.frame inView:self.popoverParentView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp | UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown animated:YES];
```

The problem is that everything appears correctly with one exception: the navigation bar is invisible, but the title text and the bar button still show up and work correctly. I've tried messing with the bar's `hidden` and `tintColor` properties and changed the size of the popover, but nothing changes.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see it.

I have other examples of similar things in my project's codebase, but those appear correctly. Any ideas as to why this is happening or how I could fix it?

[image: Invisible bar]

**EDIT**

Not sure if the following will help, but I'm hoping it will provide some clues as to what's really going on here to someone who's seen something like this before.

I pushed a new (blank) view controller onto `popoverNav` just to see what would happen. It pushes and animates perfectly. Everything looks right except that the nav bar is still transparent and the bar button items are pushed to the top of the view.

[image: After pushing a new view controller]

Comment: Have you perhaps done any `UIAppearance` customization of `UINavigationBar` elsewhere (e.g. setting the background image)?

Comment: Also, it seems a bit fishy that you initialize your `UIView` with just `init`, instead of `initWithFrame:` which would be the designated initializer for `UIView`, but I'm not sure if that really contributes to the problem (besides, assigning an empty view is redundant because `UIViewController` would create its own view automatically).

Comment: @omz, nope I haven't done anything like that.

Comment: I was able to get the look I wanted by using a custom `UIViewController` without a `UINavigationController` and adding a `UINavigationBar` in Interface Builder. Still not sure why what I was doing before doesn't work, so I'll leave the question open in case anyone can solve it for future answer seekers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just tried the exact same code and the navigation bar shows up fine here. I'd suspect that it might have something to do with the `UIViewController` category you mentioned...

Comment: You could be right. I'll be looking through that code. I added the category for the background, and another dev on the project later added some confusing code that I don't think belongs in there.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not the main cause of the problem, but it looks like the `UIDatePicker` is clipped by the `CGSize` you have setup. As far as I can remember, the default height for the picker is 216 (which you have) but you haven't taken into consideration the required height for the `UINavigationBar`.

I'm not sure why the background of the view looks to be some kind of textured grey unless this is set in your `UIViewController` but it doesn't appear that way from the code you pasted. This certainly isn't a default texture for iOS though.

Perhaps try and make your `CGSize` a little larger to accommodate the contents of the view as it looks as though the "Done" button is hugging the top right corner where there should be a fair few points worth of spacing around this by default.

Also, is there a reason why you're creating a new view and assigning it as the view property of your view controller?

```
UIView* popoverContentView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
popoverContentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
// Add some stuff to popoverContentView

popoverViewController.view = popoverContentView;
```

Why not add the content as subviews of the view instead?

Comment: As for the size issue, you're right. I've played around with the size and whether I make it larger, the exact right size, or anything, the same problem occurs. The background is something I did in a category off of `UIViewController` (works perfectly everywhere else). And I don't remember why I created a new `UIView` instead of using the existing one, but I have tried your suggestion to no avail. I will try playing with the size and your `UIView` suggestions again for a sanity check. Thank you.

Comment: Nope, no difference. I set the `popoverContentSize` to the height of the navigation bar + the height of the date picker. I'm also now using `popoverViewController.view` in place of `popoverContentView`. The whole date picker fits now, but that's the only difference.

Comment: How odd. I'm at a loss as to what to suggest. Clutching at straws but have you tried creating a custom `UIViewController` and assigning your `UIPickerView` as an ivar?

Comment: I haven't. I'll give it a shot and let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly enough, I get the same result when I do it that way.